# Create a conditional subset array with selective keys

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a conditional sub-set of an array.

I have an array `allBooks` which has properties such as `type`,`author`,`id` etc.

In a particular view I want to show only some of properties based on a condition.
For example; displaying summarized properties of all the books in stock.

Here is what I have tried:

```
let booksInStock: any[] = [];

this.allBooks.forEach(book => {
// Add only when book is in stock
if (book.isInStock) {
    // Get only few keys from all the available keys
    let temp: any = {
      typeOfBook: book.targetType,
      author: book.author,
      bookId: book.id,
      bookDisplayName: book.value,
      bookName: book.bookName
    };
    // Add to the summarized or filtered list
    booksInStock.push(temp);
  }
});
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Not really, but it would look maybe a bit cleaner. I would use `filter + map`. Like https://jsfiddle.net/mL1uwo17/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `map` would be more semantic, like so:

```
let booksInStock = this.allBooks
  .filter(book => book.isInStock)
  .map(book => ({
      typeOfBook: book.targetType,
      author: book.author,
      bookId: book.id,
      bookDisplayName: book.value,
      bookName: book.bookName
      })
  );
```

If efficiency is your priority however, a `for` loop is faster.  See this link for an example: https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
// This function is pretty generic, you can find one in e.g. underscore.js or Ramda:
const pluck = fields => item =>
  Object
    .keys(item)
    .filter(key => fields.includes(key))
    .reduce((result, key) => {
      result[key] = item[key]
      return result
    }, {})

// Create filter+map+pluck -settings for different 'views':
const inStock = books => 
  books.filter(b => b.isInStock)
    .map(pluck(['targetType', 'author', 'id', 'value', 'name']))

// Invoke them:
const booksInStock = inStock([
  { isInStock: true, author:'harry', otherFIeld:'not-included' },
  { isInStock:false, author:'notharry'}
])
```